# Passing a JPanel to a method to draw rectangles

Tags: java, graphics

I have a class with a draw method that accepts a JPanel as an argument. 
The first line in the draw method is:

```
Graphics g = p.getGraphics();
```

Where (p is the the jPanel passed as an argument to the draw(Jpanel P) method).

I want to draw different rectangles in different colors (based on conditional statements). So i use the

```
g.setColor(Color.RED) // or another color
```

Then i draw the rectangle using

```
g.fillrect(x,y,xsize,ysize).
```

When i do

```
System.out.println("color is " + g.getColor().toString());
```

I see the colors changing, but i don't see the rectangles appearing on the JPanel. This JPanel is an object inside my class that extends from JFrame. What do i need to do to see the rectangles on my JPanel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not paint by obtaining the Graphics object from the JPanel. What you should do is to subclass JPanel and override paintComponent, check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/).

The reason why is because the Graphics instance is created everytime your Panel is painted, and you have no control about it, because its parent (the JFrame) may decide when to do so. So you should never make any assumption about the Graphics instance, and you must include your painting logic in the paintComponent method.

The reason why you are not seeing your rectangles is because you are painting them with either an old Graphics instance, or because in the next rePaint they are getting erased because is not the order it is supposed to be (those calls must be in the paintComponent method).

Answer (score 1):

JPanel doesn't know that its canvas is updated, so you see nothing on the screen. The proper way is to override JPanel's method *onPaintComponent* and draw inside this method. This way, after you call JPanel.repaint() you'll see the stuff you've drawn.